# visual c++ for linux stopped (tty input)

Tags: linux, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

whenever i have a scanf statement in my code in a linux project using visuall c++ for linux ion visual studio i get the following message:

(gdb) 1021-var-delete var1

Stopped (tty input)

can anyone help me along with this?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Related to generating error: [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) and [Targeting the Windows Subsystem for Linux from Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/)

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both gdb and your program want to read from the standard input.  gdb wins.  If you want to debug a program that reads/writes on the terminal, you might want to run the program on a separate terminal, and *attach* to that process using gdb.

Further reading:

- [Running Programs Under GDB](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_5.html)